# Need a PHP button for a python script

Tags: python, php

```
<html>
 <body>

   <form method="post">

    <input type="submit" value="GO" name="GO">
   </form>
 </body>
</html>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['GO']))
    {
        shell_exec("python /var/www/html/test/test.py");
        echo"success";
    }
?>
```

```
import sys
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
import pytest
import time
import paramiko

sys.stdout = open('logs.txt','a')
today = date.today()
# datetime object containing current date and time
now = datetime.now()

# mm/dd/YY H:M:S
dt_string = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
print("Logs:", dt_string)

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect('IP', username='root', password='pw')
print("Connected")
#stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('sudo reboot')
print("Rebooted")
print("----------")
print("<br></br>")
```

It isn't executing in the PHP button. I don't know if this code is proper. Anyone have any ideas why it isn't working on the PHP side I tried using flask didn't have any luck. I don't know if it's even possible what i'm trying to do. Anyone have any ideas? The top is PHP and bottom is the Python code.

Comment: [shell_exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) might be returning some useful information, but you're ignoring it, and say "success". Instead try this: `echo shell_exec("python /var/www/html/test/test.py");`. Note that you didn't say you saw the "success" message...

Comment: I'd have expected it's possible to do everything that the python script does directly in PHP. That might make it less brittle.

Comment: echo shell_exec("python /var/www/html/test/test.py");  didn't show results, it was showing "successful" but no log file was coming in my files.